# how to prevent a java process from being killed by killall java -9

Tags: java, process, kill

Whenever I type killall java -9 ,all java process is killed, even if i change the process name.
So Is there an way to protect the java process being killed by 'killall java -9'

Comment: Making a program that cannot be terminated from command prompt seems kind of...dangerous

Comment: -9 is SIGTERM, which I believe there is no way to ignore that.  And, it is the PROCESS being killed instead of THREAD

Comment: @Jeffrey that's what I'm thinking too :/

Comment: You could run another (non-Java) process to restart your Java process when it unexpectedly closes.

Comment: I think that the best answer is "just don't do it".  (Like you wouldn't run "rm -rf" in the root directory!)

Comment: Hello Jilen, can you [edit] your question and add some background as to what you are trying to achieve?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simple solution is to **run the process with a different user**.  Then, you (as your current user) would not have permission to kill all processes called `java`, unless you were `root`.

---

I, `deltik`, do not have a `java` process running.  `top` shows:

```
Processes: 80 total, 3 running, 1 stuck, 76 sleeping, 435 threads      21:22:54
Load Avg: 1.66, 1.47, 1.40  CPU usage: 33.49% user, 2.65% sys, 63.85% idle
SharedLibs: 7552K resident, 4480K data, 0B linkedit.
MemRegions: 15059 total, 1858M resident, 32M private, 372M shared.
PhysMem: 298M wired, 2332M active, 1289M inactive, 3918M used, 176M free.
VM: 164G vsize, 1041M framework vsize, 490174(73) pageins, 7225(0) pageouts.
Networks: packets: 1543452/932M in, 1286039/414M out.
Disks: 103231/3309M read, 218839/2343M written.

PID   COMMAND      %CPU  TIME     #TH  #WQ  USER
1159  java         108   02:28:38 45/2 1    somebody
1769  top          4.0   00:10.32 1/1  0    root
765   bash         0.0   00:00.00 1    0    deltik
...
```

So this is my output when I try `killall -9 java`:

```
Deltik-iMac:~ deltik$ killall -9 java
No matching processes belonging to you were found
```

I cannot kill a `java` process owned by `somebody`.

Comment: Nice,+1. @jilen you could also use kill instead of killall to kill only the specific processes that need to go.

Comment: @terdon there is another script that use killall, I think I should better not change it

Comment: By run java as another user , I cannot access the home folder of the user.

Comment: You would presumably know the password of that user, so you could `su somebody`.